# Trim null spaces and concatenate

Tags: datastage

I need to concatenate two fields in datastage and one field contains `null` values and I am using the `NVL()` function. My requirement is that if there are `null` values they shouldn't appear as spaces.

I am doing like:

```
Trim(NullToEmpty(Database.ADDR_2)) : ' ' : Trim(NullToEmpty(Database.ADDR_3))
```

Here `ADDR_3` has `null` values and if it is `null` then I should trim the spaces and should display only `ADDR_2`. Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not completely clear - if you used NVL there should not be the need to use NullToEmpty.

You could use something like this:

```
IF IsNull(Database.ADDR_3) THEN Database.ADDR_2 ELSE Database.ADDR_2 : " " : Database.ADDR_3
```

Add trims if needed.

Comment: Hi Micheal,I have only used NullToEmpty function and used Trim and the spaces are no more appearing. Thanks for your answer